# camera calibration change orientation of axis

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I want to solve for the extrinsics by using direct linear transformation on corresponding 3D LIDAR points  and 2D camera points. I already have the intrinsics.

Problem is, points behind the camera gets re-projected as well (see picture below).

[image]

So I constrain to only points "in front of the camera", i.e z > 0. The problem is, on different trials where different sets of points are used, the produced extrinsic matrix produces differing axes. Sometimes, constraining z > 0 gives the right results (centre part of image), whereas other times I need z < 0, which I believe to be the z-axis going into the camera. So the question is, how do I constrain the Z axes of the camera to be sticking out of the camera?

```
def with_intrinsic(points2d, points3d, intrinsic):
    cam1_K_inverse = np.linalg.inv(intrinsic)

    #direct linear transformation calibration, assumes no intrinsic matrix
    assert points2d.shape[0] >= 3
    assert points3d.shape[0] == points2d.shape[0]

    A = []

    points2d_homo = []
    for u,v in points2d:
        points2d_homo.append([u, v, 1])

    points2d_homo = np.array(points2d_homo).T #columns to be data points


    points2d_inv = np.dot(cam1_K_inverse, points2d_homo).T
    assert points2d_inv.shape == (points2d.shape[0], 3)
    assert points2d_inv[0, 2] == 1

    for idx in range(points2d.shape[0]):
        x3d, y3d, z3d = points3d[idx]
        u, v, _ = points2d_inv[idx]

        A.append([x3d, y3d, z3d, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -u * x3d, -u * y3d, -u * z3d, -u])
        A.append([0, 0, 0, 0, x3d, y3d, z3d, 1, -v * x3d, -v * y3d, -v * z3d, -v])

    A = np.array(A)

    U, D, VT = np.linalg.svd(A)
    M = VT.T[:, -1].reshape((3, 4))

    error = get_reprojection_error(points2d, points3d, intrinsic, M)
    logging.debug("error with_intrinsic: %s", error)

    return M
```

update:  I tried to check if re-projecting 1 of the "training" points will yield me z < 0. If so, I do a `np.dot(R, extrinsic)` to rotate the point about PI radians around 1 of the axis. I've tried all 3 axes but that still don't seem to yield the correct result.

```
R1 = np.array([
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, np.cos(pi), -np.sin(pi)],
        [0, np.sin(pi), np.cos(pi)],
    ])

R2 = np.array([
        [np.cos(pi), 0, np.sin(pi)],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [-np.sin(pi), 0, np.cos(pi)],
    ])

R3 = np.array([
        [np.cos(pi), -np.sin(pi), 0],
        [np.sin(pi), np.cos(pi), 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
])
```